# Getting OSX Safari to honor css "white-space: pre"

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I have a blog where I am using ccs style="white-space: pre" with div elements.   I am doing this to display lots of code samples or cli output within the blog.. and have to copy and paste that text into the html pages.

I want the source code to be easily readable, so wish to use "white-space: pre" to preserve the white space formatting of the original output when displayed by the browsers.

Chrome and Firefox display the html pages just fine, but for some odd reason... Safari is doing "pre-wrap" when I ask it to do just "pre". I must have the preserve whitespace and nowrap combined features... which is "pre" but is not being honored by safari for osx.

Does anyone have any workaround for this type of problem? It is clear to me from plenty of testing that firefox and chrome support "pre" as defined by CSS white-space property but safari for osx does not.  I do not want to use &nbsp as this makes my source htm difficult to read and manage.

thanks in advance for any HELPFUL advise.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference. Could you add a working example? Are you using an old OS/Safari version? Have you tried the `<pre>` Tag instead of a div with `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: with futher testing i found that when i host the code on a local html file, my text is no pre-warped, "pre" works fine with all browers including safari.  the same code hosted on blogger.com, the text is pre-wraped on safari only, so very weird.  there is something odd with the themes of blogger.com and safari specifically i guess.  i tried every theme and they all did the same thing.  the code and screenshots of the problem are now listed here

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/blogger/3NBxnf3sues/9jBYjpcODwAJ

Answer (score 9):

I have had this same issue occur on Safari 11.0.3, with a  in a jQuery dialog box with "whitespace: pre" formatting. Using a pre tag instead did not fix the issue.

However, adding "word-wrap: normal" to the style for the  worked. Here is the final css that I found to work for my scenario:

```
padding: 15px;
white-space: pre;
word-wrap: normal;
resize: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 2):

Safari incorrectly makes `overflow-wrap` (aka `word-wrap`) apply even when `white-space` is `pre`. The spec says it should not apply when wrapping is disallowed in the first place, but Safari seems to ignore that.

So, to fix this, combine `white-space:pre` with `word-wrap:normal`, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still finding this as of March 2018 in Safari 11. Block elements, e.g. `<div>`s, with `white-space: pre;` and `overflow: auto;` behave differently in Safari than Chrome, Firefox, or Edge. Text will wrap within the container instead of scrolling as it should, as shown in the image Neal included on his post on Google's forums.

The workaround is to use a `<pre>` element. Safari handles that appropriately, and the other browsers handle it the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
padding: 15px;
white-space: pre;
word-wrap: normal;
resize: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It's Working for me ..
Th

Comment: Explain it please